# .htaccess; How to rewrite two folders to one?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Let's say I have links like this:

```
http://www.example.com/media/images/my_file123.jpg
```

I want to rewrite this to:

```
http://www.example.com/my_images/my_file123.jpg
```

Means: Rewrite `/media/images/` to `/my_images/`.

How can I do this with `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following Rule

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^my_images/(.+)$ /media/images/$1 [L,NC]
```

This rewrites **/my_images/image.ext** to **/media/images/image.ext** .

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/redirects/), it seems like you can just write 
`Redirect /media/images/ /my_images/`

Assuming that this is all relative to the root of your web folder.

Comment: I don't want to redirect. I want to open `http://www.example.com/my_images/my_file123.jpg` this should get the file `my_file123.jpg` in `/media/images/` on my server.